# MS Access linked Table displays incorrect / wrong data type

Tags: sql-server, xml, ms-access, odbc, dsn

Any SQL Server tables linked via `ODBC/DSN` from `MS Access` with the `SQL` `XML` Data type show as "Short Text" in MS Access.  Note, this worked fine on the older "SQL Server" `ODBC` driver which will not work without `SSL` 2/3.  Fine, meaning, the MS Access linked table would show as "Long Text" for the `SQL Server` `XML` data type.

Any ideas why `MS Access` thinks `SQL Server` `XML` data type is "short text" (255 chars max)?

- Server:
  Windows 2012 R2
  SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.7469.6
- Client:
  Windows 10 
  MS Access 2016
  ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

```
UPDATE dbo_table SET myXML = '*' WHERE row_id=1 -- or anything
```

Error message on table update:

> "Update on linked table failed... unexpected end of input."